# Rendering part of form in main view

Tags: ajax, yii2, partial-views, active-form

Is there any way to render partial view using AJAX that is a part of form which other part starts `ActiveForm->begin()` in main view?

**Controller:**

```
    public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new order();

            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ActiveForm::validate($model);
            }

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

                try {
                    if ($model->save()) {

                        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success', 'New record has been saved.');
                        return $this->redirect(['index']);
                    }
                }
                catch(yii\db\IntegrityException $e) {
                    Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', 'Cannot save new record. Please try again.');
                    return $this->redirect(['index']);
                }
            } 
            else {
                return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model, ]);
            }
        }

public function actionSpecialdetform()
    {
        $model = new order();
        return $this->renderAjax('_specialform');
    }

public function actionDetform()
    {
        $model = new order();
        return $this->renderAjax('_form');
    }
```

**View** (main - create.php):

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\order */

$this->title = 'Create';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Orders', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="order-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true,]); ?>

    <div class="panel panel-default wizard" id="order-wizard">
        <div class="wizard-steps clearfix" id="form-wizard">
            <ul class="steps">
                <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span>Order</li>
                <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span>Details</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="step-content clearfix">
                <div class="step-pane active" id="step1">
                    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'order_date')->input(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="step-pane" id="step2">                  
                    <div id="order-details">
                </div>
                </div>
            <div class="actions pull-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-prev wizard-btn" disabled="disabled"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" style="margin-right:5px"></i> Previous step</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-next wizard-btn" data-last="Save">Next step <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" style="margin-left:5px"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<?php

$js = '

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#order-wizard").on("change", function(e, data) {
        if(data.step===1 && data.direction==="next")
        {
            var date = $("#order-order_date").val();
            if(date==="")
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            var form = null;
            if(date === "2015-01-01")
            {
                form = "/order/specialdetform"
            }
            else
            {
                form = "order/detform"
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: form,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#order-details").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

';
$this->registerJs($js, \yii\web\View::POS_END);
?>
```

**Partial View** - (_specialform.php):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'promo_code')->input(); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'Surname')->input(); ?>
```

**Partial View** - (_form.php):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'Surname')->input(); ?>
```

I don't want to just create one partial view, because this is only one different field, but it's an example.

Comment: Could you add code for better problem understanding?

Comment: @arogachev I've attached code in my first post. Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.